# How to create a customizable User Interface with swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I've searched through google, but there doesn't seem to be anything on this. In almost every user interface, you can resize parts of it in order to make it more custom (from the users perspective). For instants, in eclipse, one can resize the consul relative to the area with the code by clicking on the spot in-between the two panels/parts and dragging. One can also click and drag the area in between the Package Explorer and the rest of the parts in order to resize that. How would I do this? By "this", I mean allow users to resize the amount of space given to each part of the layout? How do I get the little division-sign-like curser to show up? What layout should I use?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be describing a [`JSplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html).

Take a look at [How to use Split Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) for tones of examples